# Swing Game EyeHandCoordination

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, gui

Question copied from the book:

> (Game: eye-hand coordination) Write a program that displays a circle
>   of radius 10 pixels filled with a random color at a random location on
>   a panel, as shown in Figure 16.28c. When you click the circle, it
>   disappears and a new randomcolor circle is displayed at another random
>   location. After twenty circles are clicked, display the time spent in
>   the panel, as shown in Figure 16.28d.

My solution:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class EyeHandCoordination extends JFrame {
    private final int CIRCLE_RADIUS = 10;
    private final int TOTAL_CIRCLES = 20;
    private RandomCirclePanel panel = new RandomCirclePanel();

    public EyeHandCoordination() {
        add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EyeHandCoordination frame = new EyeHandCoordination();
        frame.setTitle("EyeHandCoordination");
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }



    private class RandomCirclePanel extends JPanel {
        private long startTime;
        private long endTime;

        private int circleX = 0;
        private int circleY = 0;

        private int currentCircle = 0;

        public RandomCirclePanel() {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    // Check if in circle
                    if (inCircle(e.getX(), e.getY()) && currentCircle < TOTAL_CIRCLES) {
                        currentCircle++;
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        /** Display circle at a random location **/
        private void changeCircleLocation() {
            circleX = (int)(Math.random() * (getWidth() - CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2)); 
            circleY = (int)(Math.random() * (getHeight() - CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2));
        }

        /** Check if inCircle **/
        public boolean inCircle(int mouseX, int mouseY) {
            if (distanceFromCenterOfCircle(mouseX, mouseY) <= CIRCLE_RADIUS) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private int distanceFromCenterOfCircle(int x, int y) {
            int centerX = circleX + CIRCLE_RADIUS;
            int centerY = circleY + CIRCLE_RADIUS;

            return (int)(Math.sqrt((centerX - x) * (centerX - x) + (centerY - y) * (centerY - y)));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            changeCircleLocation();

            if (currentCircle >= TOTAL_CIRCLES) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
                String s = "Time spent: " + ((endTime - startTime) / 1000.0) + " seconds";
                g.drawString(s, width / 2 - fm.stringWidth(s) / 2, height / 2 - fm.getAscent());
            }
            else {
                g.setColor(new Color((int)(Math.random() * 256), (int)(Math.random() * 256), (int)(Math.random() * 256)));
                g.fillOval(circleX, circleY, CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2, CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public boolean inCircle(int mouseX, int mouseY) {
    if (distanceFromCenterOfCircle(mouseX, mouseY) <= CIRCLE_RADIUS) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Can be

```
public boolean inCircle(int mouseX, int mouseY) {
    return distanceFromCenterOfCircle(mouseX, mouseY) <= CIRCLE_RADIUS;
}
```

---

`(int)(Math.random() * (getWidth() - CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2));`

`g.setColor(new Color((int)(Math.random() * 256), (int)(Math.random() * 256), (int)(Math.random() * 256)));`

Looks like you could benefit from a function that takes an integer as maximum value... and then returns an integer between 0 and max minus 1.

Which does exist - you'd simply create a new instance of [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) and then call [`randomInstance.nextInt(maxValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-).

---

Lastly, I think you would be better off by renaming the `currentCircle` variable to `amountOfCirclesDisplayed` because that's what it really is. `currentCircle` seems to point to the idea that somewhere, you have a list of circles, and right now, you're working on 1 specific circle. But that's not true, because you HAVE no list of circles and all that really matters is how many you've displayed so far.

Comment: Regarding the first point: I'm not quite sure why I wrote it that way lol. Question regarding the second point: I read somewhere in my book that it generally takes a lot of resources to create objects; would be more efficient to use Random anyway in this case? And yes, now I realize after you mentioned it that currentCircle is not a good name for that field haha. Thanks for your thorough reply!!

Comment: @Legate that's premature optimization, you'd benefit more from the readability than the speed